# C program for Ideal Weight Calculation for Male, Female

Tags: c

I have written the following program to check ideal weight for Male and Female based on **Height** and **Gender**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    float height, mminima = 48, fminima = 45, iw;
    char gender;

    printf("Please Enter your Age,Height(in CM) and Gender\n");

    scanf("%d\n%f\n%c", &age, &height, &gender);

    if((gender = 'M') && (height < 152.4))
    {
         iw = mminima - (152.4 - height) * 1.1;
         printf("\nYour idle Weight should be= %f", iw);
    }
    else
    {
         iw = mminima + (height - 152.4) * 1.1;
         printf("\nYour Idle Wight should be= %f", iw);
    }

    if((gender = 'F') && (height < 152.4))
    {
        iw = fminima - (152.4 - height) * 1.1;
        printf("\nYour Idle weight should be= %f", iw);
    }
    else
    {
        iw = fminima + (height - 152.4) * 1.1;
        printf("\nYour Idle weight should be= %f", iw);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But output always shows my ideal weight for Male and Female both, if statement is not comparing gender. Why? Where am I wrong? Please help!!

Comment: create a common function then pass parameters like gender and other parameters and return result from that. that would be a best programming approach.

Comment: Read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Understand what that article says and use it.

Comment: user3121023 thanks a lot :) that sure was a mistake, but still output is not as desired, still same thing happening.

Comment: As the other commenters already mentioned. `gender='F'` will always be true. To avoid this kind of errors (everybody run into this - belive me) I would recommend to always put the constant in the first place. So instead of writing `gender == 'F'` write `'F' == gender`. If you miss a `=` 
(`'F' = gender`) the compiler will tell you right away.

Comment: I think you meant **ideal weight**, not **idle weight**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues should be corrected:

1) Faulty comparisons:

```
if(gender='M') // always true; should be if(gender=='M')
if((gender = 'F') // always true; should be if(gender=='M')
```

2) Logic of the program is faulty, it would print `Ideal Weight` for female and male
if the height is above `152.4`

3) Lots of the repetitive code which should be encapsulated in the functions.

4) Lack of error handling for wrong gender symbol.

5) Proper spelling and printout is needed. Correct: `Idle Wigh`

6) There is no need to print weight as `74.3456789`
One digit after `.` is sufficient.

7) The constant magic numbers should probably be defined outside main, like:

```
#define MAGIC_HEIGHT 152.4
```

8) Clarity of the program can be improved with the use of `switch` and `case`:

Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define M_MIN         48.0
#define F_MIN         45.0
#define FACTOR         1.1
#define MAGIC_HEIGHT 152.4

void print_ideal_weight(float iw)
{
    printf("\nYour Ideal weight should be = %.1f", iw);
}

float calculate_ideal_weight(float m, float height)
{
    float iw;

    if(height < MAGIC_HEIGHT){

        iw = m - (MAGIC_HEIGHT - height) * FACTOR;
    }
    else{
        iw = m + (height - MAGIC_HEIGHT) * FACTOR;
    }            
    return iw;
}

int main()
{
    int age;
    float height, iw;
    char gender;

    printf("Please Enter your Age, Height(in CM) and Gender(F/M): \n");

    scanf("%d\n%f\n%c", &age, &height, &gender);

    switch (gender)
    {
        case 'M':
            iw = calculate_ideal_weight(M_MIN,height);
            print_ideal_weight(iw);
        break;

        case 'F':
            iw = calculate_ideal_weight(F_MIN,height);
            print_ideal_weight(iw);
        break;

        default:
            printf("Unknown gender entered!\n");
        break;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please Enter your Age, Height(in CM) and Gender(F/M):                                                             
25                                                                                                                
176                                                                                                               
M                                                                                                                 

Your Ideal weight should be = 74.0
```

Comment: thank you every one :). i m trying to learn C by myself. Your valuable answers have added more to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

your if statment `if((gender='M')&&(height<152.4))` requieres both conditions to be true... then your `else` section will be prformed regardless of gender.

if the height is above 152.4 both `else` statments will run regardless of gender

you should seperate the two conditions:

```
if(gender=='M')
{
    if (height<152.4)
    {
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
if(gender=='F')
{
    if (height<152.4)
    {
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
```

as previous comments stated you should change `gender='F'` to `gender=='F'`

Answer (score 2):

The logic in the code is wrong. Firstly you have a typo

```
if((gender='M')&&(height<152.4))
```

`gender='M'` is an assignment and will always return true.

Secondly, if either of the conditions are false it does the `else` part - ie when `gender` is `'F'`. You need to split up your `if` into separate conditions. First check the `gender` and then once you've confirmed it equals `'M'`, then you can check the `height`, like this:

```
if(gender=='M')
{
    if(height<152.4)
    {
        iw=mminima-(152.4-height)*1.1;
        printf("\nYour idle Weight should be= %f",iw);
    }
    else 
    {
        iw=mminima+(height-152.4)*1.1;
        printf("\nYour Idle Wight should be= %f",iw);
    }
}
```

And then then you want to do an `else if` for the check for `gender` equalling `'F'` like this:

```
else if(gender=='F')
{
     if(height<152.4)
....
```

because `gender` can only ever be one of two valid values, so if it matches one, it cannot match the other. You could add a final `else` to handle situations where the `gender` is neither `'M'` or `'F'` and report an error.

Comment: just note that he (and you) made an assignment `gender='F'` insted of logical equales `gender=='F'`

Comment: @Dagan good catch...should have paid more attention when I cut'n'pasted that line :/